# Postgres fetch query returning boolean error

Tags: php, postgresql

Can someone please help explain why I am getting errors with Postgres query?

I have tried both variances of pg_fetch & pg_object in my query, but I continue to get a warning error:

**Warning: pg_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /opt/vhosts/body.php on line 45**

Can someone help confirm that my query is correct, or if my assumption that I am getting a boolean return because I am not getting a response from the server for my specific table - therefore issue with server or db access...

I've checked DB connection, it is good and connected.

Here is my query:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

    require_once ('.db.conf.php');
    $db = pg_connect($dbstr_RW);
    //$login = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];

 $result = pg_query($db, "select * from user");

?>
```

Here is my result array - logic is select all from user table and output city data within that table.

```
<?php

while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo $row['city']."<br>";
}

echo "</ul></div>";

?>
```

Comment: Error handling is missing in your code, that's why you don't see the real error.

Answer (score 1):

You may not be connected to database because as per [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-connect.php) `pg-connect` return `FALSE` on failure. That's why `pg_query($db, "select * from user");` gives error.

For [pg_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php) it requires resource to database connection as first optional parameter.